# Does "Domestic Girlfriend" manga continue after anime ending?

Tags: domestic-na-kanojo

I want to buy the *Domestic Girlfriend* manga. The problem is I don't want to buy it if both the anime and manga finished off on the same ending.

Does the manga continue after the show ended?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the series continues in the manga. Even better yet, the manga is still ongoing meaning there are still new chapters to come even.

As it stands there are 24 volumes, containing 251 chapters total.
Most of which are available for Kindle e-readers through [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06Y18MJKW)

Comment: You can also read the entire series with a Crunchyroll Manga subscription, with new, translated chapters released roughly one day after they drop in Japan.